# TypeError: utilData.map is not a function issue

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object, array.prototype.map

I have the following code within my React component:

```
  const [utilData, setUtilData] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {    
      ws.current.onmessage = e => {
          const data = JSON.parse(e.data);
          console.log("data: ",data);
          setUtilData(data)          
      };
  }, []);
```

The console.log of data returns the following information, which should be stored within the `utilData` state.

```
[
    {
        "env_name": "the-matrix",
        "score_one": 24,
        "memory": 1024,
        "cpu_temp": 66.4
    }
]
```

The issue that I am not sure about and can't see what I am doing wrong, is when I attempt to access each property using the `.map` array method over `utilData`, i.e:

```
  return (
    <div>
        {
          utilData.map((data, i) => (
            <span>{data.env_name}</span>
          ))
        }

    </div>
  )
```

I am getting the error: **TypeError: utilData.map is not a function** and unsure why

Comment: Have you tried logging out `utilData` to see what that is coming out at before its mapped? If this matches what you're seeing on `data` If you're able to share the full component instead of individual snippets it might help confirm if anything else is affecting things

Comment: try updating to utilData ? utilData.map((data, i) => (
            <span>{data.env_name}</span>
          )): null
also do you see any data in  console.log("data: ",data);

Comment: @RNair - yes I do see data from my `console.log("data: ",data)` which I have actually mentioned in my question and shown the output.

Comment: @RNair - seems like the ternary operator solved the issue. so `utilData` was empty during processing. Pls add this as an answer and I will mark it as the accepted solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

update return below snippet, since initially utildata might ben ull

```
return (
    <div>
        {
          utilData ? utilData.map((data, i) => (
            <span>{data.env_name}</span>
          )) : null
        }

    </div>
  )
```